# Rails Sunspot merging hit highlighting with content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, sunspot-rails

Im trying to highlight my search results using the sunspot gem while displaying more information then just the hit. Essentially I'm trying to highlight more then just the hits that are generated through @search = Sunspot.search().

controller

```
 def search
   @search = Sunspot.search(A, B, C) do 
  keywords params[:search] do 
    highlight :title, :description
  end
```

view

```
<ul class="search_results">
<% @search.each_hit_with_result do |hit|%>
 <ul>
<h3> hit.result.title </h3>
 <p><%= hit.highlight(:description).format { |word| "<span class=\"highlight\">#{strip_tags(word)}</span>"}.html_safe %></p> 
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

css

```
.highlight {
 background-color:yellow;
}
```

right now this code is showing a list of titles and then small one line hit. Im trying to make the search results more aesthetically pleasing. My thought was maybe to try and grab the line before and after the hits.